# WP7 ObservableCollection sorting

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sorting, observablecollection

I have a collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<Shops> ShopList { get; set; }
```

then after i put 4 elements in it(it is displayed correctly), i try to sort them

```
ShopList.Clear();
var orderedlist = ShopList.OrderBy(k => k.Name);
foreach (Shops s in orderedlist)
    ShopList.Add((Shops)s);
```

ShopList now has 4 null elements. Why is that, and how to correct the code?
Thanks

Comment: `ShopList.Clear();` clear a list :)

Comment: yeah, i'm dumb, wrong order :DD

Comment: Maybe you are interested in `SortedObservableCollection`: http://phillters.wordpress.com/2009/05/14/sortedobservablecollection/

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct order:

```
var orderedlist = ShopList.OrderBy(k => k.Name);
ShopList.Clear();
foreach (Shops s in orderedlist)
    ShopList.Add((Shops)s);
```

Comment: thats not good for me, orderedlist will have null elements if you clear shoplist, i managed to solve it buy copy the elements to new collection, then clear